# Pyqtgraph GLMeshItem set rotation with quaternion

Tags: python, 3d, pyqt, quaternions, pyqtgraph

I'm working on a real-time visualization for IMU data. The idea is to display a 3D object and update its attitude from the IMU data. From the IMU, I get the quaternion representing the device's attitude.

The sphere is initialized in the **init** as a mesh object.
In the redraw method, I want to rotate the sphere, setting the attitude equal to what I get from the IMU quaternion.

I could not find a way to rotate the mesh with the quaternion, so I'm trying to use the Euler angles as a workaround.
However, it seems the conversion to Euler (a,v) is not working properly. As a result, the mesh is not rotating properly.

What is wrong with my implementation? Do you have any suggestion on how I could implement it properly?

Full code

```py
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QQuaternion, QVector3D, QVector4D
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

class QuatAnimation(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data_queue:mp.Queue) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Rotating Vector Animation")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.data_queue = data_queue
        self.q = QQuaternion(QVector4D(0, 0, 0, 1))

        self.view = gl.GLViewWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.pan(0, 0, 0)
        self.view.setCameraPosition(distance=5, elevation=15)

        g = gl.GLGridItem()
        g.scale(2,2,1)
        self.view.addItem(g)
        self.view.addItem(gl.GLAxisItem())


        self.mesh = gl.MeshData.sphere(rows=10, cols=20)
        colors = np.ones((self.mesh.faceCount(), 4), dtype=float)
        colors[::2,0] = 0
        colors[:,1] = np.linspace(0, 1, colors.shape[0])
        self.mesh.setFaceColors(colors)
        self.obj = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=self.mesh, smooth=False)

        self.view.addItem(self.obj)

        # setup redraw timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.redraw)
        self.timer.start(int(1000/65))  # ~65 fps
        
        self.show()

    def redraw(self):
        if not self.data_queue.empty():
            item = self.data_queue.get_nowait() #item = [time, x, y, z, w]

            self.q = QQuaternion(QVector4D(item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4]))
            v = self.q.vector().normalized()
            a = self.q.scalar()
            self.obj.resetTransform() # reset every loop, since we h
            self.obj.rotate(a*2*180/np.pi, v.x(), v.y(), v.z())


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()
        event.accept()


def plot(data_queue:mp.Queue):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QuatAnimation(data_queue)  # input queue with quaternion data
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot()
```

Comment: Hi Yaxit, I'm not that familiar with quats but I think if you call self.q.normalize(), then call  "axisAndAngle = q.getAxisAndAngle()", that should give you the correct axes and angle (there are some online checkers you can use to verify the result).

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Any clue of what vector() and scalar() are actually used for?

Comment: Great you got it sorted! I think the vector and scalar part can be thought of as an axis and an angle of rotation respectively in this context.

Comment: @Yaxit and @gremto, as in [Using quaternions as rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations), the ```q.scalar()``` is ```cos(theta/2)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted a quaternion into a transformation matrix incorrectly.
See [Using quaternions as rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations).

Do like this using the `QQuaternion.getAxisAndAngle()`.

```
...
q = QQuaternion(1, 2, 3, 4).normalized()
axis, angle = q.getAxisAndAngle()

mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(...)
mesh.resetTransform()
mesh.rotate(angle, axis.x(), axis.y(), axis.z())
...
```